# Object-c cannot access viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, view

---

SOLUTION: [Blogpost](http://www.n00bdev.com/archives/5)

---

Im using Titanium for application development and am trying to create a new module to extend application functions.

1) Module is up and running - FIX!
2) Adding "customs" / functions to module - ERR.

Im following this http://iosguy.com/2010/09/04/presenting-pdf-files-by-yourself/
and im really unsure where what how and why i need to put those functions, how i create the mentioned views and so on.

So heres what i got so far:
Ive read that comas3breezepdfModule.m file is the one i need to work with so funcitons from the above link are pasted in this .m file as follows:

```
-(CGPDFDocumentRef)openDocument:(CFURLRef)url
{
    CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
    if (myDocument == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (CGPDFDocumentIsEncrypted (myDocument)
        || !CGPDFDocumentIsUnlocked (myDocument)
        || CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument) == 0) {
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(myDocument);
        return 0;
    }
    return myDocument;
}

-(CGPDFDocumentRef)document 
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"presentation" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdfdocument = [self openDocument:(CFURLRef)url];
    [url release];
    return pdfdocument;
}

- (void)load {
    UIViewController* controller = nil;
    NSInteger numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages([self document]);
    for (NSInteger pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= numberOfPages; pageIndex++) {
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage([self document], pageIndex);
        PDFPageView *pageView = [[PDFPageView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollView.bounds];
        pageView.page = page;
        pageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        pageView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        pageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:pageView];

        [pageView release];
    }
}
```

I've then tried to create a new viewcontroller subclass  where i got a PDFPageView.h and PDFPAgeView.m file... but what ever i try and test i still end up with bunch of errors  on creating pageView object in load function.

as follows:

```
comas3breezepdfModule.m: error: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'scrollView'; did you mean 'UIScrollView'?
comas3breezepdfModule.m: error: Semantic Issue: Property 'page' not found on object of type 'PDFPageView *'
comas3breezepdfModule.m: error: Semantic Issue: Property 'autoresizingMask' not found on object of type 'PDFPageView *'
comas3breezepdfModule.m: error: Semantic Issue: Property 'autoresizesSubviews' not found on object of type 'PDFPageView *'
comas3breezepdfModule.m: error: Semantic Issue: Property 'backgroundColor' not found on object of type 'PDFPageView *'
comas3breezepdfModule.m: error: Semantic Issue: Unknown receiver 'scrollView'; did you mean 'UIScrollView'?
comas3breezepdfModule.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Method '+addSubview:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Can anyone point me to right direction ?

Worst part is that i work with Java, JS, AS3 on daily basis but as soon as i open up something with xCode my mind goes blank and im not even sure what a function is anymore.
Been trying to understand the logic here time to time allmost 5 weeks now but it feels like im going backwards and understanding even less...

Answer (score 0):

All of the errors indicate that compiler can not find declarations of various parameters. Please verify that you have added appropriate header files and have also synthesized all declared properties.

Comment: Hm. im unsure actually. 

Here is my PDFPageView.h content:

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface PDFPageView : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    CGPDFDocumentRef *pdfdocument;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

@end`

and i've tried to synthesize scrollView and pdfdocument in PDFPageView.m file but those generate errors as well

Answer (score 0):

You should show your .h file, and errors generated in it, There are a few possibilities, and one of them is that the PDFPage class is not in your search path .... normally the folders (lib..) where the frameworks are stored and the fix is to add the search path via clicking on the app icon and modifying the build settings.... search paths!